# Difficulties with sending mail from GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I'm trying to send an email from within Google App Engine.

Whenever I try to send, I get a "Missing subject error".

When I run the code on the development server, it seems to work fine - the console output looks right and I'm taken to the page that I was expecting.  But when I upload it and run it, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 636, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/spam-tool/1.349401522260793315/spam-tool.py", line 34, in post
    body=cgi.escape(self.request.get('content')))
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 297, in send_mail
    message.send(make_sync_call)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 799, in send
    raise ERROR_MAP[e.application_error](e.error_detail)
BadRequestError: Missing subject
```

But there's definitely a subject.

The code I'm using is:

```
> message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="admin_address@gmail.com>",
            subject="test")
        message.subject=self.request.get('content')
        message.to = addr_to_send_to
        message.body = self.request.get('content')
        message.send()
```

(Yes, the subject is set twice... I've tried only setting it in one place or the other, and neither worked.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def email_member(request):
  to_addr = request.POST.get('email_to')

  if not mail.is_email_valid(to_addr):
    # Return an error message...
    pass
  else:
    # note we can also send html email, e.g. html='<html><head></head><body>Hello world</body><html>'
    mail.send_mail(
      sender='admin@yourdomain.com',
      to=to_addr,
      subject=request.POST.get('email_title'),
      body=request.POST.get('email_body'))
```

I suggest you also send your email within the taskqueue, so you could setup something like this, you could pass over a unique parameter so that you are less likely to be hacked.

```
def mail_member_information(email_to, email_title, email_body):
  taskqueue.add(
    url = 'email_message',
    params =
    {
      'email_to': email_to,
      'email_title': email_title,
      'email_body': email_body,
      'valid_guid': 'ae9e34ca-a2c5-476e-b8be-72d807e3dc6b'
    }
  )
```

If you just want to send to the administrators then use this:

`mail.send_mail_to_admins(sender='admin@yourdomain.com',
                               subject=request.POST.get('email_title'),
                               body=request.POST.get('email_body'),
                               html=request.POST.get('email_body'))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is what is throwing you off... but sender should be like this:

```
sender = '<admin_address@gmail.com>',
```

you are missing the '<' for the sender. Sometimes it throws an error downstream of where the actual error is.

Also, make sure the admin_address@gmail.com is a Google Account that has been added as a developer for that app.

Comment: Good suggestion, but that was what I already had - I should've edited to make it clearer that I'd changed that piece of code before posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can send like this, make sure that sender is a admin of the app

```
from google.appengine.api import mail
mail.send_mail(sender="something@gmail.com",

                 to=email_valid.email,
                 subject="Please validate your email",
                 body=body_text,
                 html=htmlbody_text)
```

Comment: You can - I'd tried that way, and it didn't work, so I tried the more object-oriented way that I posted in case that it fixed things.  It didn't.

Comment: @svaha Can you tell me what exactly is the error when you tried the above code